# Misalignment of badges/numbers on user-profile page

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, badges, user-profile-page

The current user-profile page shows the badges/numbers looking like this:

[image]

Here is a similar view of the top-bar:

[image]

I think the vertical alignment of the badges in the user-profile view should match that of the top-bar.

Tested on:

- Chrome 39.0.2171.95 m
- Firefox 34.0.5
- Internet Explorer 11.0.9600.17498

Comment: Can't reproduce in Firefox 31.3-ESR with this profile http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5764/werner, is all profiles or one in specific?

Comment: @Braiam: All the ones on TeX.SE and Meta.TeX.SE; nowhere else.

Comment: repro for me on ask different.

Comment: Reproduced on Chrome 40.0.2214.111 m, Windows 7. I'm suspecting it has something to do with the font choice, because if you highlight them, the badges are actually vertically centered, but the text seems too high. (Edit: I was talking about the badges on this post, on the user profile, the text is centered, but the badges are too low)

Comment: [This has been fixed](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6061/site-design-updates-are-live#comment17279_6070) as part of a [new site design that rolled out recently](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/6061/5764).